# Как внедрить свой код в чужой exe-шник?

Tags: exe

У меня есть какой-либо exe файл и я хочу добавить в него свой код (так сказать дополнить или как-либо редактировать). Есть ли возможность сделать такое, если да, то как?

Comment: дизассемблировать

Comment: троян что ли ;) ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795446/appending-data-to-an-exe

Comment: Victor VosMottor,нет не троян,обычная программа для теста,тренируюсь :)

Comment: Возможность есть. Как именно - зависит от того, что хотите сделать.

Comment: Alexander Petrov, есть просто программа,в которую я хочу добавить свой код и чтобы она работала также как и раньше,но с изменённым кодом

Comment: Данил, программа написана на C#(я не знаю,что значит .net язык и относится ли C# к нему)

Comment: ... Относится...

Comment: О...Хорошо,а какой например дизассемблер,можно скачать(ну или какой посоветуете)?

Comment: ILDasm, .NET Reflector, dotPeek, JustDecompile.

Comment: Скачать DotPeek,но редактировать не могу,что делать?